# Different typesettings of Y fraktur

Tags: fonts

`\mathfrak{Y}` is being displayed as

[image]

instead of

[image]

is the reason an incompatibility between the included libraries:

```
\usepackage{physics, amsmath, enumitem ,amssymb, kpfonts, hyperref, makeidx, float, leqno, media9, tcolorbox, empheq, mdframed, xcolor, setspace, dsfont, graphicx, booktabs, xcolor, multicol, tikz, longtable, braket, fancyhdr, xfrac, fontspec, comment, xeCJK, bbm}
```

Comment: With this simple code, I get the requested (2nd example) fraktur Y: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{Y}$
\end{document}`.  So what are you doing in your code that is different?

Comment: De you truly need each of those libraries?

Comment: It is the `kpfonts` package that is changing your fraktur fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first fraktur Y you showed is the one from the package [`kpfonts`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/kpfonts). Since you load this package, it is no surprise to get this specific fraktur Y. If you want to use `kpfonts` but to use the fraktur alphabet which is loaded by `amssymb`, you could load it separately, after loading `kpfonts`. If I'm not mistaken, `amssymb` uses Euler fraktur, which can easily be loaded with the package [`mathalpha`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) (which I love).

Here's a small example to use `kpfonts` with Euler fraktur.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[frak=euler]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
Here's some text with \texttt{kpfonts}, and here's the desired fraktur Y: \( \mathfrak{Y} \). 
\end{document}
```

[image]